# Numpy Concatenate Images into Array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a bunch of images that I want to store into an array.

The problem is that all my images are different sizes and I don't want to necessarily change their size, because some will be square and some aren't.

I tried using `np.concatenate` but someone online said it was better to construct a zero matrix and fill it.

However, using

```
image = misc.imread(filename)
```

from the scipy library. The image is returned as a 3 dimensional array. How should I construct my numpy ndarray if I want to store all the images in it?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you are trying to store a bunch of images of different sizes that are each stored as separate numpy arrays. If your images are gray scale (meaning 2D, as opposed to RGB which are 3D - a channel for R, G and B), you could store the images as the third dimension, filling in the absent pixels with 0s. But the best way would be to just use a python list (or tupple maybe) that stores a list of your numpy array images. That way they can be different sizes. i.e.: img_list = img1, img2, img3, etc.

Answer (score 0):

storing them in a list may be easier, the list will store them as array() objects and size wont matter, when you do operations on them, just reference the list elements.

Comment: I was thinking about that. However, I am using Theano library, and I think they require numpy arrays..

Comment: which axis would you add it to if it were concatenated? as a new row, column, 3-d Dimension?

Comment: unless you need to do an operation on the entire array the elements themselves will still be numpy arrays in a list btw

Comment: Should I make the image into a 1d array?

Comment: I'm new to numpy so this is that I was thinking. I would have a numpy array where the 1st element is the 3d array representation of the first image. The 2nd element is the 3d array representation of the second image and so on. Thus, I guess concatenating them is wrong. I want to insert them into a numpy array where element is an arbitrary sized matrix.

Comment: I would not flatten the image, from what it sounds like you can use a list, for example. list = [numpy.arange(4),numpy.arange(5)], print list[0] outputs array([1,2,3,4]) where array([1,2,3,4]) is actually a numpy object! otherwise, you will have a harder (not impossible) journey if your arrays are different sizes